# Unity 2D box collider falls into another and than ports Playercollider upwards

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to make my first Unity 2D game (it should end up to be a brawler) and i have a little problem with my colliders. My player collider straight falls a little bit into my scene colliders(the player starts ) and than the program realizes that this shouldn`t happen. It ports the player upwards. Now the player falls again and again he ports upwards. After 3 ports the player lands on the ground and can be used until he collides with another edge and than the same problem occures. I can even fly straight into the scene() collider itselfe sometimes i glitch out but sometimes i fall father down...
Can someone say me how to fix this?
Greetings and thanks for all answers
(BTW. I am sorry for my bad English i hope u can understand it)

Comment: Could you put the code of the collider in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can play with [Unity's physics 2D settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html).

Most relevant to your problem seem to be:

- Position Iterations (try to raise it)
- Velocity Threshold (try to raise it)
- Min Penetration For Penalty (try to lower it)
- Baumgarte Scale (try to lower it)

A more accurate physic simulation is more expensive at runtime so try fixing your issue by tweeking just enough or your game will get slow.